# App Title, Header Title and Header Subtitle Override?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

Has anyone else been experiencing any "override" issue with their custom Titles? For example try the public URL:

http://bhgis.org/apeg/test/viewer/

Watch closely as the titles quickly override to the default.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a few things that help answer this question: Prior to 1.3.4 you set the Page Title, Header Title, and Header Sub-Title parameters in the index.html config file as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <meta name="application-name" content="cmv">
        <meta name="description" content="CMV - The Configurable Map Viewer. Community supported open source mapping framework. Works with the Esri JavaScript API, ArcGIS Server, ArcGIS Online and more. Make it your own!">
        <meta name="author" content="cmv.io">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png">
        <title>Configurable Map Viewer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20compact/esri/css/esri.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme/flat/flat.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cmv-theme-overrides.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body class="cmv flat">
        <div class="appHeader">
            <div class="headerLogo">
                <img alt="logo" src="images/rocket-logo.png" height="54" />
            </div>
            <div class="headerTitle">
                <span id="headerTitleSpan">
                    Configurable Map Viewer
                </span>
                <div id="subHeaderTitleSpan" class="subHeaderTitle">
                    make it your own
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <div id='geocodeDijit'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headerLinks">
                <div id="helpDijit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var s = window.location.search, q = s.match(/locale=([^&]*)/i);
            var locale = (q && q.length > 0) ? q[1] : null;
            window.dojoConfig = {
                locale: locale,
                async: true
            };
        </script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.0.3/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20compact/"></script>
        <script src="js/config/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the new releases they allow users the ability to override the index.html config for the page title, header title, and sub-title in the main.js config file as shown in the screenshot below:

```
// http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/i18n.html
define({
    root: {
        basemaps: {
            davidRumseyMap1812: 'David Rumsey 1812',
            earthAtNight: 'Earth at Night',
            landsatShaded: 'Landsat Shaded'
        },
        bookmarks: {
            nullIsland: 'Null Island',
            usa: 'USA'
        },
        find: {
            louisvillePubSafety: 'Find A Public Safety Location By Name',
            sf311Incidents: 'Find Incident By Code/Description'
        },
        identify: {
            louisvillePubSafety: {
                policeStation: 'Police Station',
                trafficCamera: 'Traffic Camera'
            }
        },
        viewer: {
            operationalLayers: {
                damageAssessment: 'Damage Assessment',
                louisvillePubSafety: 'Louisville Public Safety',
                restaurants: 'Restaurants',
                sf311Incidents: 'San Francisco 311 Incidents'
            },
            titles: {
                header: 'Configurable Map Viewer',
                pageTitle: 'Configurable Map Viewer',
                subHeader: 'make it your own'
            },
            widgets: {
                bookmarks: 'Bookmarks',
                directions: 'Directions',
                draw: 'Draw',
                editor: 'Editor',
                find: 'Find',
                help: 'Help',
                identify: 'Identify',
                measure: 'Measurement',
                layerControl: 'Layers',
                legend: 'Legend',
                locale: 'Locale',
                print: 'Print',
                streetview: 'Google Street View'
            }
        }
    },
    'es': true,
    'fr': true,
    'pt-br': true,
    'pt-pt': true
});
```

Comment: Please remember to take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include details about how to do what you are suggesting, and what it does to solve the problem.  Please [edit] your answer to expand with more information.